# Reading an integer string in the form of xxx,yyy,zzz with python

Tags: python, string, integer

Is there a built in easy way to convert a string into an integer, with the format of the string being xxx,yyy,zzz? like 325,121,565 instead of 325121565. I know I can build a function that does that but I was wondering if someone else has already done so that I wont reinvent the wheel.

Comment: +1 for not wanting to reinvent the wheel

Comment: Just delete the commas using `strip(",")` and then create an integer `val = int(str)`.

Comment: `.strip()` won't delete anything in the *middle* of a string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set an appropriate locale, then use [`locale.atoi()`](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html#locale.atoi).

```
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'en_US')
'en_US'
>>> locale.atoi('123,456,789')
123456789
```

Comment: This works for the native locale: locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')

Comment: Y'know sometimes in Python your instinct is to do something quick & dirty (take a string & replace all commas with nothing, then int the result), and then you find out there's a way that's about a bagillion times more elegant.  This is one of those times. :)

Comment: @Adam: Thank you for flying Guido's Time Machine, have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
'en_US.utf8'
>>> locale.format("%d", 325121565, grouping=True)
'325,121,565'
```